# Consulta SQL: Poner en negrita los valores de un campo en un concatenado en XML

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta sql:

```
SELECT 
  t.ContentID
  ,'<' + STUFF(
        (
            SELECT  tt.Descripción_de_la_Acción + ' - ' + SUBSTRING (tt.First_Published_Date,4,20) + ' - ' + tt.Notas AS [text()]
                FROM ##TEMP_ACCIONES_COMPLETO_B AS tt  
                INNER JOIN Jasper.dbo.A_RIESGOS_ACCIONES AS tu
                ON tt.ContentID = tu.Riesgos_ContentID
                And t.ContentId = tu.Acciones_ContentID
                WHERE tt.ContentID = tu.Riesgos_ContentID  --AND
                AND tt.Notas IS NOT NULL 

            FOR XML PATH('p')
        ), 1, 1, '')  AS Valores
```

De esta manera quiero obtengo valores en párrafos.

Lo que necesito que que el campo `tt.Descripción_de_la_Acción` aparezca en negrita. Si le añado los tags `<p>` no funciona correctamente.

¿Cómo se podría realizar?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres que aparezca en negrita? Eso no tiene nada que ver con SQL Server. El formato se realiza en la aplicación cliente.

Comment: Cuando muestro esta consulta en la aplicaicion del cliente lo interpreta como un html y al tener los tags de <P> lo mete como párrafo. Pero necesito que el campo Descripción_de_la_Acción aparezca en negrita. Hay que tener en cuenta que es un concatenado que agrupa los textos en un solo campo

Comment: has probado a usar `<b>Texto en negrita</b>`?

Comment: Hola, he probado a concatenarlo en el campo: <b> tt.Descripción_de_la_Acción </b> pero si lanzo la query  aparece lo siguiente: &lt;b&gt;&lt;b&gt;

Answer (score 0):

Estimado.

el tag `<p>` define un parrafo, para colocar tu texto en negrita debes indicar tu texto entre los tag `<b>` [HTML b Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp)

Comment: Ok, el problema es el que indico en los comentarios mas arriba. Que si lo concateno la query no lo interpreta bien. Y solo quiero que salga en negrita esa parte del concatenado, no toda la columna